# Extjs controller select to listen to event on multiple types of components

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, controller, extjs4.2

I have a form controller in ExtJS 4.2.2 in which I would like to listen for a change event on any kind of form field or combobox or even a grid on the form.

What is the best way to do this.  What I have now is:

```
    // Form event subscriptions
    this.control({

        'myform field' : {
            change : function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                // do work here
        },
        'myform combobox' : {
            change : function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                // do work here
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried doing `'myform field|combo'` but it blew up.

Comment: `combobox` extends field, so you only need the first.

Comment: @Evan Good point, but question still stands as I `htmleditor` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for `myform field, myform combobox`. `,` stands for or like in css.